# Disable slick cloning slides while infinite:true

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I need to remove slick-cloned slides from my slider while keeping infinite true.How can I achieve this?

```
$(".contents")
      .not(".slick-initialized")
      .slick({
        infinite: true,
        variableWidth: true,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        prevArrow:
          '<a href="#" class="scroll-control scroll-left hidden" ><i class="icon-chevron-left "></i></a>',
        nextArrow:
           '<a href="#" class="scroll-control scroll-right" ><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>',
});
```

Comment: What's the goal here? Are the cloned slides creating issues somehow? Trying to remove them completely will probably mess up Slick and may end up just creating another problem.

Comment: Yes, it's the problem for SEO. Clonning content is bad. Someone can help with this?

Answer (score -1):

It may solve your cloning problem. please use   **infinite:false**

```
$(".contents")
      .not(".slick-initialized")
      .slick({
        infinite: false,
        variableWidth: true,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        prevArrow:
          '<a href="#" class="scroll-control scroll-left hidden" ><i class="icon-chevron-left "></i></a>',
        nextArrow:
           '<a href="#" class="scroll-control scroll-right" ><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>',
});
```

Comment: hum but If we need to loop again? I mean after the last slide we need to continue with the first one, but without cloning the slides, how can we do that?

Comment: I didn't check that way. you can test it and share your findings. happy coding :)

Comment: This issue popped up for me today and I found this page searching for a solution. The question I *still* have is how to "remove slick-cloned slides from my slider while keeping infinite true." This answer is useless -- it does the opposite. The question literally says "keeping infinite true!"